# Live Templates - schema

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, live-templates

In Delphi 2007 live templates schema namespace is defined as "xmlns="http://schemas.borland.com/Delphi/2005/codetemplates" but unfortunately borland.com isn't available any more.

- Have anybody seen/have backup of this schema?
- Is this namespace location changed in newer Delphi versions and eventually what is this location?
- Is live templates schema changed in newer Delphi versions?
- Is there information source about l.t. better than http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Live_Templates_Technical_Info with links?

Comment: There is no requirement for a namespace URL to refer to any actual addressable resource.

Comment: I wrote that wikia article. As far as I am aware there is no more complete information and also no updated information on live templates available. I doubt that anything has changed since it was added to Delphi, though. We would have heard about it a 1000 times. As far as I know there never was any official documentation on live templates, only some examples from Borland employee and Delphi user blogs.

Comment: I had the same question in the past and never found an archive copy of schema.